# copy files from source folder to target based on excel list

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this to try and copy photos that exist in the list within a list in excel. it seems check but doesn't see anything in the source folder and returns the "Does N" from the code below. I have enabled macros and the folders don't see locked. any help would be much appriciated

```
 Option Explicit

Sub CopyFiles()
    Dim iRow As Integer         ' ROW COUNTER.
    Dim sSourcePath As String
    Dim sDestinationPath As String
    Dim sFileType As String

    Dim bContinue As Boolean

    bContinue = True
    iRow = 1


    ' THE SOURCE AND DESTINATION FOLDER WITH PATH.
    sSourcePath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\source\"
    sDestinationPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TARGET\"

    sFileType = ".jpg"      ' TRY WITH OTHER FILE TYPES LIKE ".pdf".

    ' LOOP THROUGH COLUMN "A" TO PICK THE FILES.
    While bContinue

        If Len(Range("A" & CStr(iRow)).Value) = 0 Then    ' DO NOTHING IF THE COLUMN IS BLANK.
            MsgBox "Process executed" ' DONE.
            bContinue = False
        Else
            ' CHECK IF FILES EXISTS.

            If Len(Dir(sSourcePath & Range("A" & CStr(iRow)).Value & sFileType)) = 0 Then
                Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value = "Does N"
                Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Bold = True
            Else
                Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value = "On Hand"
                Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Bold = False

                If Trim(sDestinationPath) <> "" Then
                    Dim objFSO
                    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

                    ' CHECK IF DESTINATION FOLDER EXISTS.
                    If objFSO.FolderExists(sDestinationPath) = False Then
                        MsgBox sDestinationPath & " Does Not Exists"
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    '*****
                    ' HERE I HAVE INCLUDED TWO DIFFERENT METHODS.
                    ' I HAVE COMMENTED THE SECOND METHOD. TO THE SEE THE RESULT OF THE
                    ' SECOND METHOD, UNCOMMENT IT AND COMMENT THE FIRST METHOD.

                    ' METHOD 1) - USING "CopyFile" METHOD TO COPY THE FILES.
                    objFSO.CopyFile Source:=sSourcePath & Range("A" & CStr(iRow)).Value & _
                        sFileType, Destination:=sDestinationPath

                    ' METHOD 2) - USING "MoveFile" METHOD TO PERMANENTLY MOVE THE FILES.
                    'objFSO.MoveFile Source:=sSourcePath & Range("A" & CStr(iRow)).Value & _
                        sFileType, Destination:=sDestinationPath
                    '*****
                End If
            End If
        End If

       iRow = iRow + 1      ' INCREMENT ROW COUNTER.
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, I just removed it, new to forums and didn't know what to leave in.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t be creating a new `FileSystemObject` on every iteration. Also, the destination folder can only be checked once - no need to check it every time.

See below your code with a few changes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFiles()
    On Error GoTo Errproc

    Const sSourcePath As String = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\source\"
    Const sDestinationPath As String = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TARGET\"
    Const sFileType As String = ".jpg"

    'validate destination folder
    If Len(Dir(sDestinationPath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Destination path does not exist..."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim iRow As Integer
        iRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rr As Range, r As Range
    Set rr = Range("A1:A" & iRow)

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each r In rr
        With objFSO
            If Not .FileExists(sSourcePath & r.Value & sFileType) Then
                r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Does N"
                r.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = True
            Else
                r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "On Hand"
                r.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = False

                objFSO.CopyFile sSourcePath & r.Value & sFileType, sDestinationPath, True 'Overwrite
                'objFSO.MoveFile Source:=sSourcePath & r.Value & sFileType , Destination:=sDestinationPath
            End If
        End With
    Next r

Leave:
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Errproc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Kostas K. I have copied the Target path an added to the code and copied it into my .xlsm and it now says, Target path does not exist... as per the coding. The folder is not locked. Any further help is greatly appreciated. PD937

Comment: Hmm.. Have you changed 'username' to the actual username?

Comment: yes, i open the file and copied the exact location in IE and pasted it in the same format as written in your code

Comment: C:\Users\Username\Desktop\TARGET

Comment: Just tested it and it's working fine. Check the paths, is the user's name in the machine called 'Username'?

Comment: Strange, i have checked it on two machines making the path correct too. the path isn't Username i have exchanged it.

Comment: I am wondering whether a workflow that i am doing is not correct. i have an excel sheet with macros enabled as per various posts, i have a source folder with .jpg's in it and a list of the .jpg's i want to move in the sheet. i have the second folder, the destination folder named as per above.

Comment: Yep, sounds right. Create a test folder in C:\ drive, set it as the destination folder and make sure the list of files in excel do not have the '.jpg' extension already in the file name. If they do have it, remove it from here: `sSourcePath & r.Value & sFileType`.

Comment: Const sSourcePath As String = "C:\source\"
    Const sDestinationPath As String = "C:\TARGET\"
    Const sFileType As String = ".jpg"                                                                        trying the above, the list of photos to copy read as DSC0820.jpg which matches the file name but i believe that the problem is with my folders not the .jpg i am trying to copy. i tried removing the file types just in case too